# How to dynamically change static urls in an Angular application in every component

Tags: django, angular

I have an Angular application that I am using alongside a Django application. In Django we have something like this

`<img src="{% static 'folder/file.png' %}" />`

where we can change the static urls dynamically based on our environment. (Example, I can have static files pointing to my local machine vs I can have them deployed in AWS S3, changing it in one place in the application, will change it everywhere.)

How can I implement something similar in Angular, where I can change the `static_url` dynamically based on the environment. I would like this to work on all the components within my application.

Example:

When using `ng serve` it could be `<img src="/assets/file.png" />`

But when using `ng build` it  would be `<img src="https://s3_bucket_url/assets/file.png" />`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the environment files, and you can have multiple environments such as prod, dev, local, etc.

```
// In environment.ts
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  staticFileUrl: '/assets/'
};

// In environment.prod.ts
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  staticFileUrl: 'https://s3_bucket_url/assets/'
};

// In environment.local.ts
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  staticFileUrl: '/assets/'
};
```

After that you can work with that enviornment in your component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.css']
})
export class ExampleComponent {
  imageUrl: string;

  constructor() {
    this.imageUrl = `${environment.staticFileUrl}file.png`;
  }
}
```

And work with this.imageUrl inside HTML

```
<img [src]="imageUrl" />
```

In the package.json, you can set up custom scripts that can build with a specific environment.

```
"build:prod": "ng build --configuration production",
"build:dev": "ng build --configuration development",
"build:local": "ng build --configuration local",
```

And in angular.json,

add the corresponding configuration.

```
"configurations": {
  "production": {},
  "development": {},
  "local": {
    "fileReplacements": [
      {
        "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.local.ts"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

There is also an option to have just one environment file, which after building and deploying to the server, may need to be changed in some cases.

In such a case, I recommend adding a config.json to the assets, which should have the exact same structure as the environment, and then using a service, for example: config-service.ts

This method would involve the asynchronous loading of a config.json file and replacing the environment's contents with this configuration. If you were looking for a way to work with the configuration in this manner, I could expand on my response, but this is already unnecessarily long.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I am going to try this out now.
However, I'm thinking of implementing something like this based on your answer. `<img src={{ staticFileUrl + '/file.png' }}` in my component HTMLs, so that I do not need to have lot of variables in my component.ts files. But how can I have this `staticFileUrl` globally declared so all my component HTMLs have access to it?

Comment: The correct approach is via environment. If you decide to create service, directive etc... the result will be same. And one variable in .ts is not a issue.